# Getting Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property when trying to save the data to firebase storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an input field which on entering the input and clicking the save button, the data should be saved in the firebase storage.
The code is as below,

```
<div class="md-form">
  <input type="number" id="ip1" class="form-control">
  <label for="ip1">ip1</label>
</div>
<button type="button" id="ip1_btn" class="btn btn-dark-green">SAVE</button>
```

Below is what I am trying to achieve using js,

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('demo-260b2');

    $('#ip1_btn').click(function(){
        rootRef.set({
            ip1:$('ip1').val()
            });
    })
```

While trying on the browser, I am getting the following error,

> Uncaught Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'demo-260b2.ip1'

I am unable to figure out what's wrong in this. Any help would be very much helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you provided a value of `undefined` somewhere in the object to set.  The only value you have here is from `$('ip1').val()`.  I would conclude that value is actually undefined.  You should log/debug it to see for yourself.

My guess is that you meant to use this instead: `$('#ip1').val()`.  Note the `#` in front of "ip1", which would call out the element with the HTML id "ip1".

Comment: Ah, true that!
Thanks for pointing this out, Doug! :)